# How to drop a table with a period/full stop in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

One of my classes using APEX Oracle had a couple of tables named with periods that I added to Apex successfully but now I'm unable to delete them.

The tables are named like

```
classid.groupid_table_name
```

I've tried going through the UI trying to find a way to manually drop the tables and have also run the scripts:

```
drop table classid.groupid_table_name cascade constraints;
```

which gets the error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

and

```
drop table [classid.groupid_table_name] cascade constraints;
```

which gets the error "ORA-00903: invalid table name"

The tables aren't really doing anything bad they're just kind of cluttering up the workspace since the naming scheme has since been changed to classid_groupid_table_name.

Comment: What is the actual table name in `user_tables` (or `all_tables` or `dba_tables` depending on your privileges and who owns the table)?  `clientid.group_id_table_name` would normally mean that the table is named `group_id_table_name` and was in the `classid` schema.  But I suppose it is possible that you used a case-sensitive identifier for the table name and somehow decided to use a period as a part of the table name.  If that's what happened, you'd need to enclose the table name in double quotes and the identifier would be case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried, the following:

```
drop table "classid.groupid_table_name" cascade constraints;
```

Comment: Correct,  Oracle uses quotes to for special/mixed case names.  Otherwise everything is converted to uppercase.